# Could we sample pandas data frame based on aggregate criteria

Tags: pandas, random

```
a = df[df.contribution <= 0.1].sample(frac = 0.1)
```

I need to do something like this:
take any sample of rows but total contribution from rows should be less than 100

```
a = df.sample(sum(df['contribution'])<100)
```

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your dataframe?  Do you need to take a sample where the `contribution` rows add to 100?

Comment: yes, you are correct , summation of "contribution" should not exceed 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thought being you would like the sample to contain more records than less.
Sadly using a loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,35,(15,1)),columns = ['contribution'])

for i in reversed(range(len(df))):
    if df['contribution'].sample(i).sum() < 100:
        print df
        break
```